# How to run OpenVPN

Tags: android, execute, openvpn

How to run OpenVPN from my application? I searched out for it but couldn't get any proper resources. I have a rebuilt version on windows platform.

Do I need to install it to my emulator? If so, how do I install it.
How do I run using the `cmd` from the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install it on Emulator. Use ADB command to install [OpenVPN APK](https://www.apk4fun.com/apk/6697/) on emulator and then configure it ***OR***
[Source code](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn) of OpenVPN application which can be directly run on Emulator using Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Cyanogen mod provides OpenVPN that you can access from shell.  You could run a shell command from your application.